# How can i make a specific li to be active inside a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How can i make a specific `li` to be active inside a `while` loop? The indicator will be the value of the `GET` which is `$subj = $_GET['subjdescr'];` I'm bad at javascript and css. Can someone give me ideas on how to do this? Or clues.

If i click the English 2, I want the english 2 to be active. Else if i click math, the math wil be active.
[image]

here's my code.

```
    <li><ul class="premium-menu nav nav-list collapse in">
    <?php

    $subj = $_GET['subjdescr'];

         $sql ="SELECT enroll_ref FROM std_enrolled WHERE stud_no = '$stud_no'";
           $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $enroll_ref = $row['enroll_ref'];
             }



              $sql3 ="SELECT DISTINCT subj_descr FROM subj_enrolled WHERE enroll_ref = '$enroll_ref'";
           $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);


           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
            $subj_descr = $row['subj_descr'];

    ?>
  //i want the value of the subj_descr is equals to the value of get data $subj.
 <li <?=$subj_descr=='$subj'?'class="active"':'' ?> ><a href="viewlecture.php?subjdescr=<?php echo $subj_descr;?>"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($subj_descr)); ?></a></li>
     <?php
      }  
     ?>
</ul></li>
```

Comment: you set the active class
what is the problem?
you have set css for the Active li !?

Comment: They are all active.

Answer (score 1):

use staic variable for checking

```
<?php
    static $i =0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
                $subj_descr = $row['subj_descr'];

        ?>

    <li class="<?php if($i == 0) { echo 'active';  } ?>"><a href="viewlecture.php?subjdescr=<?php echo $subj_descr;?>"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($subj_descr)); ?></a></li>
    <?php
          ++$i;
          }  
         ?>
```

Comment: Not working.. Only the first item is active. Even i click the second item still the first item is active.

Comment: you have to use jquery for that for example // <li onclick="$(this).addClass('active')" >Another</li>

Comment: put the line of code given on your while loop means if you click on that li the jquery add class active to that li :)

Answer (score 0):

use a statement in your li

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    $subj_descr = $row['subj_descr'];
 ?>
     <li <?=$subj_descr=='English 2'?'class="active"':'' ?>><a href="viewlecture.php?subjdescr=<?php echo $subj_descr;?>"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($subj_descr)); ?></a></li>
 <?php
  }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Not working. What should i put to 'your active value'?

Comment: @nethken which one do you want to activate? does it have a certain value?

Comment: I want to activate what users click. Example i clicked the "English 2" I want that to be active.

Comment: after user click, will the page be redirected to a new page with a parameter in url or how can you use it?

Comment: The same page sir.

Comment: As you can see there are variables passed.  `href="viewlecture.php?subjdescr=<?php echo $subj_descr;?` I think this is the indicator what you clicked.

Comment: This is the variable i used to `get`  $subj = $_GET['subjdescr'];

Comment: Why can't i use a variable there?